# How to set tabindex on forms fields?

Tags: django

How do i set the html attribute "tabindex" on form fields?

My template currently looks like..

```
<div class="field text username">
   <label>Email Address</label>
   {{ form.email }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overide the widget and provide an attrs dictionary with the tab index set:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#django.forms.Widget.attrs

Answer (score 20):

The tab index is a feature of the layout, and so it feels like it really belongs in the *template*, not in the *view*. Here's a straightforward approach that achieves this:

First, define a [custom template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters) that adds a `tabindex` attribute to the widget of a bound field:

```
@register.filter
def tabindex(value, index):
    """
    Add a tabindex attribute to the widget for a bound field.
    """
    value.field.widget.attrs['tabindex'] = index
    return value
```

Then, add `|tabindex:n` to the fields in the template. For example:

```
<tr>
<th>{{ form.first_name.label_tag }}<td>{{ form.first_name|tabindex:1 }}
<th>{{ form.email.label_tag }}<td>{{ form.email|tabindex:3 }}
<tr>
<th>{{ form.last_name.label_tag }}<td>{{ form.last_name|tabindex:2 }}
<th>{{ form.active.label_tag }}<td>{{ form.active|tabindex:4 }}
```

Answer (score 12):

All credit to Alex, but just to fill out the solution:

When using the django auto formfield generation (widgets), forget about the templates you have to do it in the form definition like this:

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    email    = forms.CharField(label=_("Email Address"), max_length=75)
```

becomes:

```
class AuthenticationForm(forms.Form):
    email    = forms.CharField(
                   label=_("Email Address"), max_length=75,
                   widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'tabindex':'1'})
                )
```

But if you're willing to abandon the widgets and keep presentation in the template you can also do it this way:

```
<div class="field text username">
   <label>Email Address</label>
   <input id="id_email" type="text" name="email" 
       tabindex="1" maxlength="75" 
       value="{{form.email.data|default:''}}"/>
</div>
```

I'm inclined toward the latter.

Answer (score 1):

All credit to John, but `{{form.email.data|default:''}}` seems to ignore any initial data provided in the form. I ended up using some jQuery to get around this painful Django shortcoming:

```
$.each({
    'email': 1
    // add other fields here
}, function (key, value) {
    $('#id_' + key).attr('tabindex', value);
});
```

combined with `{{ form.email }}` will output the input field and attach a tabindex without all the widget/attr mumbo-jumbo that is particularly unpleasant when using a ModelForm.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use [django-widget-tweaks](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-widget-tweaks) for this.

Using render_field (I prefer this method):

```
{% render_field form.email tabindex="4" %}
```

Alternatively, using attr filter:

```
{{ form.email|attr:"tabindex:4" }}
```